# How to change images in UI according to time duration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch, progress

I am doing iWatch application. In that, User has to walk for 6 minutes. In that, I am showing timer. According to that, I have to change walking images. I have change 8 images.
like image1.png, image2.png, etc to image8.png

How to change image according to time duration.

I am new to Swift language.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var walkingImage: WKInterfaceImage!
    let walkingImagesArray = ["walking1.png", "walking2.png", "walking3.png","walking4.png", "walking5.png","walking6.png", "walking7.png", "walking8.png"]

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        self.startTimer()
}

    func startTimer() {
        self.countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    @objc func updateTime() {
        count = count + 1
        if(count < 361) {
            timerLabel.setText(String(timeString(time: TimeInterval(count))))
           //here I have to use switch case to change image
        } else {
            print("Workout completed")
            countdownTimer.invalidate()
            session.end()
            builder.endCollection(withEnd: Date()) { (success, error) in
                self.builder.finishWorkout { (workout, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.session = nil
                        self.builder = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print("\(count)")
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: every 4 minutes, I have to update the image, I have given updateTIme code @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative- bro , can you show the updateTime where you created , and  if your time interval is < 6 min you can only show 2 images

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of less than 60 seconds resulting image is named "walking0.png"

**Solution:**

```
func image(time: Int) -> String {
    let sekInt = time / 60
    let sek = String(sekInt)
    return "walking\(sek).png"
}

self.walkingImage.setImage(UIImage(contentsOfFile: image(time:count)))
```

**Unit Tests:**

```
func testExample() {
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 360), "walking6.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 359), "walking5.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 301), "walking5.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 300), "walking5.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 299), "walking4.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 61), "walking1.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 60), "walking1.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 59), "walking0.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 1), "walking0.png")
    XCTAssertEqual(image(time: 0), "walking0.png")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start timer for 6 minutes and change your image every 6 minutes.

```
var timer: Timer?
var currentIndex: Int = 0
let walkingImagesArray = ["walking1.png", "walking2.png", "walking3.png","walking4.png", "walking5.png","walking6.png", "walking7.png", "walking8.png"]

func startTimer() {
    if let timer = timer {
        self.timer = timer

    } else {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 360, repeats: true) { timer in
            //Change your image here
            self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1
            self. walkingImage.image = self.walkingImagesArray[self.currentIndex]
        }
    }
}

func stopTimer() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timer = nil
}
```

Comment: change your image every 4 minutes. total timer 6 minutes how will u do

Comment: @shraddha11 here index comes like timer value